# How to get country list as autocomplete for combobox in XAML

Tags: wpf, powershell, xaml

I am working on a project using XAML with PowerShell, this is my first project using XAML. I have a form where user enters a country name and Combobox should autocomplete the country name. I am not able to achieve this.

XAML code for Combobox I am using as below

CountryList - I am picking it from a csv file and CountryList is the Header column. It's not working for me. Any help on this, please?
I am using PowerShell script.

```
<ComboBox Name="country" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" 
Margin="194,227,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="330" FontSize="16" 
VerticalContentAlignment="Center" IsEditable="True" 
IsTextSearchEnabled="True" TextSearch.TextPath="countryList" ItemsSource=" 
{Binding countryList}"/>
```

I get the result like this.
[Combobox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5K41.png)

XAML code:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="GreenLake FlexCapacity" 
    Height="500" Width="850">


    <Grid>

        <TextBox Name="ASM" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" Margin="194,48,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="330" FontSize="16"/>
        <TextBox Name="email" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" Margin="194,104,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="330" FontSize="16"/>
        <TextBox Name="company" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" Margin="194,165,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="330" FontSize="16"/>
        <ComboBox Name="country" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" Margin="194,227,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="330" FontSize="16" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" IsEditable="True" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" TextSearch.TextPath="countryList"/>
        <TextBlock Name="ASM_name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="102,54,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92" FontSize="16" RenderTransformOrigin="0.864,0.918"><Run Text="ASM Name"/><LineBreak/><Run/></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Name="ASM_email" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="102,110,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92" FontSize="16" RenderTransformOrigin="0.864,0.918"><Run Text="ASM Email"/><LineBreak/><Run/></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Name="company_name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="66,171,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="128" FontSize="16" RenderTransformOrigin="0.864,0.918"><Run Text="Company Name"/><LineBreak/><Run/></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Name="country_name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="124,226,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="65" FontSize="16" RenderTransformOrigin="0.864,0.918" Text="Country"/>
        <Button Name="create" Content="Create ID" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="34" Margin="194,281,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="164" FontSize="16"/>
        <Button Name="cancel" Content="Cancel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="34" Margin="381,281,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="143" FontSize="16"/>
        <TextBlock Name="Cust_ID" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="48" Margin="159,348,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="389" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold"/>

    </Grid>

</Window>
```

CSV file saved [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=11dV4CGhR72kUuFczsAXDeoKZzoVdt2TU)

Code from PowerShell script:

```
$country = $window.findname("country")
$countryList = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Country-codes.csv" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Country Name' | Out-String
$country.ItemsSource = $countryList
```

Comment: What does your itemsource look like? We can't tell if it's formatted or processed properly.

Comment: `$countryList = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Country-codes.csv" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Country Name' | Out-String`
And I am calling this in XAML `ItemsSource=" {Binding countryList}`                                                                                                                        
In PowerShell am calling like below. (Not sure if this is correct way)                                                                                               
`$country.ItemsSource = $countryList`

Comment: I would remove the binding from XAML and try using just the `$country.ItemSource = $countryList` in the code

Comment: I have tried that too, but it did not make any difference. It still shows the same dropbox as a single character, not a name. Don't know why.

Comment: Could you update your question with as much code and detail to reproduce the issue? That way I can test it myself and let you know if I get the same issue. Could you also share your CSV or update your question with how it looks and some example data?

Comment: Thanks, @I.TDelinquent I have updated my question, please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using what you have given me, I removed the following parts:

- `TextSearch.TextPath="countryList"` from the combobox in XAML
- Removed `Out-String` from your CSV import

This is what I'm using:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework, System.Drawing, System.Windows.Forms, WindowsFormsIntegration

[xml]$xaml = @"
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="GreenLake FlexCapacity" 
    Height="500" Width="850">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Name="ASM" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" Margin="194,48,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="330" FontSize="16"/>
        <TextBox Name="email" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" Margin="194,104,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="330" FontSize="16"/>
        <TextBox Name="company" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" Margin="194,165,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="330" FontSize="16"/>
        <ComboBox Name="country" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" Margin="194,227,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="330" FontSize="16" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" IsEditable="True" IsTextSearchEnabled="True"/>
        <TextBlock Name="ASM_name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="102,54,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92" FontSize="16" RenderTransformOrigin="0.864,0.918"><Run Text="ASM Name"/><LineBreak/><Run/></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Name="ASM_email" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="102,110,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92" FontSize="16" RenderTransformOrigin="0.864,0.918"><Run Text="ASM Email"/><LineBreak/><Run/></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Name="company_name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="66,171,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="128" FontSize="16" RenderTransformOrigin="0.864,0.918"><Run Text="Company Name"/><LineBreak/><Run/></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Name="country_name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="124,226,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="65" FontSize="16" RenderTransformOrigin="0.864,0.918" Text="Country"/>
        <Button Name="create" Content="Create ID" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="34" Margin="194,281,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="164" FontSize="16"/>
        <Button Name="cancel" Content="Cancel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="34" Margin="381,281,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="143" FontSize="16"/>
        <TextBlock Name="Cust_ID" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="48" Margin="159,348,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="389" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
"@

$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
$window=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($reader)

$country = $window.FindName("country")

$countryList = Import-Csv -Path C:\Users\harwoodm\Desktop\Country-codes.csv | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Country Name"

$country.ItemsSource = $countryList

$window.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

And this is a screenshot of the form in action:

[image]

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you. Can we make autocomplete also show the matching items in the dropdown list? Like when you type United, in dropdown it should show 3 list items - United Arab Emirates, United Kingdom, United States only? Is it possible?

Comment: @Hari If my response answers your question, please upvote it and mark it has the answer :) I'm not sure, I've never done anything like that. Since it is a separate issue/request, this should be put into a new question as to not drift the focus on this question :)

Comment: Done. Any references links you can provide for 2nd question would be helpful. Thanks again.

Comment: @Hari Could you also upvote my answer to this question? It helps me and future visitors :)

Comment: I cannot do it, this is my first question here so.

Comment: @Hari Fair enough :-D I should've checked hehe